# onNotificationOpened works in Android emulator but not in actual device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I am using firebase notification module in my react-native application. It works perfectly in emulator but when I install the app in mobile, onNotificationOpened event listener never gets called when I open the notification. what am i missing ?

**Environment**

- Development Operating System: Windows

**Build Tools:**

- React Native version: 0.60.5
- React Native Firebase Version: 5.5.6
- Firebase Module: notifications

**Code Snippet:**

```
  this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com/');
  });

  /*
  * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
  * */
  const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
  if (notificationOpen) {
      Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com/');
  }
```

Comment: did you give the app notification permission?

Comment: @Lenoarod i am receiving the notification in mobile device. But when click on the notification none of the event listeners are fired

Comment: It worked after I add the below code in androidmanifest.xml file

<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>